# Program CodeRunner doesn't show anything in console when returning values

Tags: python, coderunner

I'm using the Mac program CodeRunner to test some Python code.
However, when I return values through functions, the console does not show these values.

ex:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

Normally evaluating square(2) would result in the console displaying 4. However, nothing appears in CodeRunner.  Is this a flaw in the program or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you actually CALL your functions or do you just define them?

Comment: Is CodeRunner a REPL? Otherwise `print` would come in handy.

Comment: Yes, I call the functions.  Still no output.

Comment: If you showed us your complete code, or a sandbox which reproduces the error, maybe someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally evaluating square(2) would result in the console displaying
>   4.

No. Normally evaluating `square(2)` should return `4` and should not display anything.

```
def square(x):
    return x**2
square(2)
```

Will show no output at all.

```
def square(x):
    return x**2
print(square(2))
```

Will output the result of `square(2)` which is `4`.